# Death Testing a constructor with GoogleTest

Tags: c++, googletest

Getting a seg fault while trying to ASSERT_EXIT object creation that throws a custom exception on bad parameters like so:

```
ASSERT_EXIT( MyObj(1,2,3) , ::testing::ExitedWithCode(1), "");
```

where the class being created is like so:

```
class MyObj
{
public:
    MyObj(int a, int b, int c) { if( a < b ) throw MyException("Error"); }
}
```

the custom exception is like so:

```
class MyException : public std::invalid_argument
{
public:
    MyException(std::string s) { /* do some logging */ exit(1); }
};
```

Is there a workaround or a better approach?

Thanks

Comment: Where is the SIGSEGV coming from? Somewhere in your code, or from the bowels of Google Test? (If it's coming from Google Test, it's a bug in Google Test and you should inform them of that)

Comment: You are calling `exit(1)` while throwing an exception? Why?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider ASSERT_DEATH if you expect unhandled exception that must terminate your application (like throwing from nothrow member or call exit explicitely)
or ASSERT_THROW if you have normal exception